# Using bash sshpass+openshh to run commands in a FOR loop

Tags: bash, quotes

I'm trying to check the existence of some files in a non-usual folder depth inside ZIP files, on several servers located in a list, eventually to run it in a bash script.

I was able to run the command on a particular server (IP) and get the output, the problem started when tried to use the server list txt file.

```
for HOST in $(cat serversList.txt)

do

"sshpass -p '*******' ssh osboxes@$HOST -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no find /home/osboxes/Desktop/script -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 7 -iname '*.zip'" -exec "unzip -l {} \; | grep '\.zip\|filename*' >$(hostname)_out.t**strong text**xt 2>$(hostname)_error.txt"

done
```

I believe that I'm not using the single/double quotes correctly (wasn't sure why attempting running directly on IP worked with " and not with ').

I'm just not that familiar with bash to know how to aggregate the expressions to make them relate to the command (like using parenthesis which I understood not applicable in a for loop).

Basically I expect the output and error be sent to the files along with the hostname of the machine it ran on. currently I'm getting an error -

```
bash: sshpass -p '*******' ssh osboxes@10.0.0.25 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no find /home/osboxes/Desktop/script -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 7 -iname '*.zip': No such file or directory.
```

Seems to me that it's not getting to extracting the ZIP to search within, I'm just not sure how to correct it.

A tip here will be appreciated :)

Update:
Following @chepner 's response, eventually I got to this, running in the shell:

```
while IFS= read -r host; do sshpass -p '*******' ssh osboxes@"$host" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \ "find /home/osboxes/Desktop/script -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 7 -iname \"*.zip\" -exec unzip -l {} \; | grep \"\.zip\|filename*\" >"$(hostname)_out.txt" 2>"$(hostname)_error.txt"; done <serversList.txt
```

I tried escaping what I thought were relevant double quotes (") of the code and removing the single" after find's **-exec** to eliminate the **missing argument to exec** error.

However after hitting enter for the above, I'm getting a new line (>) on the next line, and I can't seem to find why..

This is the content of **serversList.txt**:
10.0.0.25
10.0.0.26

I believe that the syntax combining with the fact that it's over ssh is causing this to occur but my shell skills aren't strong enough yet to see what I'm missing here.

Update 2-

Eventually I made it with:

```
while IFS= read -r host; do sshpass -p 'tds654321' ssh osboxes@"$host" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \ "find /home/osboxes/Desktop/SecPageProj/testfiles -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 7 -iname *.zip -exec unzip -l {} \;|grep '\.zip\|SecurityPage\|ERTSOC'" >$(hostname)_out.txt 2>$(hostname)_error.txt ;done <serversList.txt
```

Thanks for the direction and inspiration:)

Comment: Why are you quoting the entire command line? `bash` is doing exactly what you are telling it to do: run a command named `sshpass -p '********' ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to quote the command that needs to run on the remote host, not the entire local command line.

(Also, see [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the correct way to iterate over the lines of a file.)

```
while IFS= read -r host; do
  sshpass -p '*******' \
    ssh osboxes@"$host" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \ 
    'find /home/osboxes/Desktop/script
       -mindepth 1
       -maxdepth 7
       -iname "*.zip"
       -exec "unzip -l {} \; |
     grep "\.zip\|filename*" >"$(hostname)"_out.txt 2>"$(hostname)"_error.txt'
done < serversList.txt
```

Comment: Hi @chepner, I updated the post with an update following your recommendation.. any thoughts?

Comment: You aren't escaping the double quotes that are part of the command: `ssh ... "find ... -exec \"*.zip\" ...`

Comment: Hi @chepner, thanks again. I tried it but it didn't seem to affect.. maybe I wasn't clear enough so I edited the update and added the content of the serversList.txt, your advice is appreciated here :

Comment: After some playing around with it I made it with the command I updated last, It seems that the main issue is what I send to the remote machines and what part of the command I want to process on the executing (along with some escaping syntax I learned along the way). Thanks @chepner !

Answer (score 0):

```
while IFS= read -r host; do sshpass -p 'tds654321' ssh osboxes@"$host" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \ "find /home/osboxes/Desktop/SecPageProj/testfiles -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 7 -iname *.zip -exec unzip -l {} \;|grep '\.zip\|SecurityPage\|ERTSOC'" >$(hostname)_out.txt 2>$(hostname)_error.txt ;done <serversList.txt
```